Stuck on 0.85 AUC
I’m new to the field and learning by tackling small cases. I’m working with a neural network on an imbalanced dataset, but I’m stuck at an AUC of 0.85, and it doesn’t seem to be improving. In similar dataset with lgbm I am getting 0.97. Also in 100 optuna trials the AUC is ~0.84-0.85. Do not know ... it seems strange. Is it good option to use balanced as class weight for imbalanced dataset?
def objective_nn(trial, X_train_tuning, y_train_tuning, class_weight_dict):
    num_layers = trial.suggest_int('num_layers', 2, 5)
    units = trial.suggest_int('units', 128, 512)
    dropout_rate_input = trial.suggest_float('dropout_rate_input', 0.1, 0.3)
    dropout_rate_hidden = trial.suggest_float('dropout_rate_hidden', 0.1, 0.3)
    learning_rate = trial.suggest_float('learning_rate', 1e-4, 1e-3, log=True)
    activation = trial.suggest_categorical('activation', ['relu', 'swish'])
    optimizer_name = trial.suggest_categorical('optimizer', ['adam', 'adamw'])
    l2_reg = trial.suggest_float('l2_reg', 1e-4, 1e-2, log=True)
    batch_size = trial.suggest_categorical('batch_size', [16, 32])

    skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True, random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
    validation_aucs = []

    for fold_index, (train_index, valid_index) in enumerate(skf.split(X_train_tuning, y_train_tuning)):
        X_train_fold, X_valid_fold = X_train_tuning.iloc[train_index].reset_index(drop=True), X_train_tuning.iloc[valid_index].reset_index(drop=True)
        y_train_fold, y_valid_fold = y_train_tuning.iloc[train_index].reset_index(drop=True), y_train_tuning.iloc[valid_index].reset_index(drop=True)

        model = models.Sequential()
        model.add(layers.Input(shape=(X_train_fold.shape[1],)))
        model.add(layers.Dense(units, activation=activation, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2_reg)))
        model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
        model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate_input))

        for _ in range(num_layers - 1):
            model.add(layers.Dense(units, activation=activation, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(l2_reg)))
            model.add(layers.BatchNormalization())
            model.add(layers.Dropout(dropout_rate_hidden))

        model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

        if optimizer_name == 'adam':
            optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)
        elif optimizer_name == 'adamw':
            optimizer = optimizers.AdamW(learning_rate=learning_rate)


        model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(name='auc')])

        # Callbacks
        early_stopping = callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_auc', mode='max', patience=5, restore_best_weights=True)
        reduce_lr = callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', factor=0.5, patience=3, verbose=0)


        history = model.fit(
            X_train_fold, y_train_fold,
            validation_data=(X_valid_fold, y_valid_fold),
            epochs=50,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            class_weight=class_weight_dict,
            callbacks=[early_stopping, reduce_lr],
            verbose=0
        )

        val_auc = max(history.history['val_auc'])
        validation_aucs.append(val_auc)

    return np.mean(validation_aucs)

train_df = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH, encoding='utf-8')
train_df.columns = train_df.columns.str.lower()

X = train_df.drop(columns=['isfraud'])
y = train_df['isfraud']

plot_dir = '/content/plots'  
os.makedirs(plot_dir, exist_ok=True)

X = preprocess_data(X, MODE, DIR, SEED, plot_dir)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=TEST_SIZE, random_state=RANDOM_STATE, stratify=y)

tuning_subset_size = 0.2
X_train_tuning, _, y_train_tuning, _ = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=(1-tuning_subset_size), random_state=RANDOM_STATE, stratify=y_train)

class_weights = compute_class_weight(class_weight='balanced', classes=np.unique(y), y=y)
class_weight_dict = dict(enumerate(class_weights))

study = optuna.create_study(direction='maximize', study_name='maximize_auc')
study.optimize(lambda trial: objective_nn(trial, X_train_tuning, y_train_tuning, class_weight_dict), n_trials=N_TRIALS, n_jobs=40)

